# Upload File To Remote Server With PHP cURL

Tags: php, post

I would like to transfer a file from a web site to this web site gulfup.com using `POST`

MY CODE ( it contain a problem that no file uploaded ) :

```
<?php

$the_file = "http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-super-cache.1.2.zip";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.gulfup.com/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    'file_1_' => "$the_file"
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
    echo $response;
}

?>
```

web site code to upload from pc :

```
<form id="uploader" name="uploader" action="http://www.gulfup.com/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="form_submit();">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_1_" id="file_1_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_1_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_2_" id="file_2_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_2_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_3_" id="file_3_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_3_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_4_" id="file_4_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_4_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_5_" id="file_5_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_5_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_6_" id="file_6_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_6_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_7_" id="file_7_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_7_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_8_" id="file_8_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_8_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_9_" id="file_9_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_9_">
<div class="uploadfile"><input name="file_10_" id="file_10_" size="70" type="file"></div>
<br id="br_10_">
<br>

<span class="bn_up"><button type="submit" name="submitr" class="btn" id="submitr"><span>Upload</span></button></span>

<div class="clr"></div>
</form>
```

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: what is the error which pops up when you run this script? please specify

Comment: are you sure whether authentication for file upload is required or not?

Comment: Looks like you're only POSTing the URL to the file, not the file itself.

Comment: (( what is the error which pops up when you run this script? please specify )) no errors .. just the home page of the site only appear and the page of new link not appear

Comment: ((Looks like you're only POSTing the URL to the file, not the file itself)) .. i don't want to download the file again and then upload it again

Comment: "**I don't want to download the file again and then upload it again**". Unfortunately, you have no choice. Well, you do have a choice - 1) contact "www.gulfup.com" and ask them to change their system so you can send a URL and they download it, 2) download the file locally and then upload it, 3) give up.

Comment: My answer didn't work. Spent 20 minutes trying to figure it out. Can't be bothered spending any more time trying to help with a question which, whilst having a legitimate technical aspect is probably really targeted at abusing or misusing a file hosting service, so deleted my answer.

Answer (score -1):

seems like http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php.html you forgot about the @ (at character) in the post array

Comment: i don't know if it work or not .. but it doesn't show the page of new link not appear just a Blank page :(

Comment: I think you'll find the "@" symbol was just part of the placeholder text used in that article. The true problem is that the user is not sending the filename of a file held locally (as per the article you refer to), but is instead sending a URL of a remote file.

Comment: did you mean that the script should download the file first  some where in my site then upload it again ? .. how can i send file from my site to another upload site ?

Comment: Yes - you must download the file from the URL to your own server before trying to submit it to any other server as part of a form submission. To submit a file via CURL, read the article linked in the answer above by test30, which seems to have the same/similar code to your question.

Comment: ok .. no problem to download the file to my server , but the problem how to send the file from my server to gulfup.com .. i tried to use test30 answer, but i failed

Answer (score -1):

Try editing the first line

```
$the_file = "http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-super-cache.1.2.zip";
```

to

```
$the_file = fetch_remote_file("http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-super-cache.1.2.zip");
```

Comment: `fetch_remote_file()` is NOT a standard PHP function.

Comment: Lucanos is right .. fetch_remote_file() is NOT a standard PHP function

Comment: I realise that you are new to Stack Overflow, but providing solutions with a non-standard function and with the expectation that anyone reading it will "google that function" and find the same resources you may be finding today is not inline with the community goals and standards here.